# Difference between adt and data structures

Tags: data-structures, abstract-data-type

Stack is an example of an abstract data type, stack is an example of a data structure  but yet abstract data types are different  from data structures  how come?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance specifies that, "Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @RobertColumbia  I am new here on stack overflow, and no it's not an home work help, I'll be entering the university anytime soon for computer science so I just read PDFs to prepare my self ,,,,now the concept of abstract data types and data structures confuse me 

Comment: Did you try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)?

Answer (score 5):

You can think of an ADT (Abstract Data Type) as collection of **operations** (i.e. `add`, `remove`, `insert` that define how the ADT behaves on a collection of data elements. At the ADT level, the exact way that the data is stored is hidden; hence the *Abstract* in Abstract Data Type. The big idea here is to hide the way data is presented to make it more accessible to others. Examples include `Map` and `Que`.

A data structure, on the other hand, actually **implements** those operations that define the ADT's behaviour. Examples include `Array` and `List`.

In more practical terms, you'll typically see an ADT defined in two files: 1) an **interface file**, which specifies the required operations; 2) an **implementation file**, which implements those operations using a specific data structure.

This is why you'll see something like `public interface SomeList<T>` at the head of interface files and `public class SimpleLink<T> implements SomeList<T>` at the head of implementation files — the `implements` is a "promise" to implement all of `SomeList<T>`'s methods.

Comment: List is generally an ADT and is sometimes used to refer to one of multiple data structures (e.g. in Python a `list` is an array). Did you mean linked-list?